# Keeping ReSharper happy with switchable layouts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2, resharper-7.1

In an MVC project I have a number of views that can be displayed in two "modes", where a different layout file is used for each mode.

To achieve this, I am setting the layout file using the appropriate [`Controller.View`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470743%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) overload.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View("Index", "_IndexLayout");
}

public ActionResult Dialog()
{
    return View("Index", "_DialogLayout");
}
```

Both of the layout files have a `@RenderSection("PageJavascript")`, and the views have a `@section PageJavaScript`.

Here comes the tricky part: ReSharper's solution wide analysis is complaining about this, giving an error of *Cannot resolve section 'PageJavaScript'*.

Is there an alternative approach to layout switching I can use that will allow ReSharper to know that I am using a layout file that contains this section?

Comment: Could you not default it to the most common one, then set it to the layout specified in the controller when the param is present?